# getBoundingClientRect() is not working on safari

Tags: javascript

I have used getBoundingClientRect() for a menu and is not working on safari. It works fine on iphone's mobile browser, chrome and firefox but on safari web browser it is not working.

```
<div class="menuDiv" id="menuDivId">
    <div class="menu" id="menuId">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="borderBo">
              <a class="active" id="booking" href="#book">Booking</a
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>


<div>

.
.
.
  lots of text
.
.
.
.

</div>


<div class="bookings" id="bookingScroll">
</div>

<div>

  .
  .
  .
    lots of text
  .
  .
  .
  .

</div>
```

js:

```
var bookingScroll = document.getElementById("bookingScroll");
document.getElementById('booking').addEventListener('click', function(){
  window.scrollTo({
    top: bookingScroll.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
})
```

edit: I came up with a solution in jquery that works on safari.

Comment: `it is not working` is not a helpfull description of the problem. Do you get an error message in the console of the browser? What value do you get for `bookingScroll.getBoundingClientRect().top` and what value do you expect?

Comment: There is no error in the console. the click event fires and then nothing happens after that. Btw, I have few more items on the menu and there is lot of text content before this tag  `<div class="bookings" id="bookingScroll">`. I'll edit to sort the confusion.
</div>

Comment: What value do you get for `bookingScroll.getBoundingClientRect().top` and what value do you expect?

Comment: It is different with different screen size: 1407.875, 1385.5, 1744.296875 ... and so on. with full size screen, firefox gives:1520.800048828125. safari gives 1519.875.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are better answers. This is the solution for my case:

https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1)
  {
    $('#booking').on('click', function(event) {
        $(window).scrollTo($("#bookingScroll"));
    });
  }
```